# Is there a way you can see how many people visited your github organization profile?

Tags: github, github-organizations

Is there a way you can see how many people visited your github organization profile?

It's clear that there is a way to look at visitors, clones etc. in individual repos, but is there a way to see how many people visited your organization?

For example, I am part of this https://github.com/CognitiveNeuroLab organization. And while I have the rights to look at everything, I can't seem to find any info on this. Including when I google it, since most people look only at their individual repo's
Thank you all for your time,
Douwe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that GitHub is providing this data.

Looking around I only found the solution to include a tracking image into you organization page and everytime someone visits the page, you can count the number of requests made to this image. Similar to how it's done for [Marketing E-Mails](https://www.nutshell.com/blog/email-tracking-pixels-101-how-do-tracking-pixels-work).

Obviously this is in no way foolproof but there seems to be a relatively active GitHub App around this concept.

[GitHub Profile View Counter](https://github.com/antonkomarev/github-profile-views-counter) that uses https://yhype.me/ for tracking

Comment: Thanks @leonhard! So the way I understand it is that for now the best thing people came up with is to look at the amount of visitors but not yet the amount of unique vistors. Which is unfortunatly, but at least it's something.